# Where Contains from two function calls

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, linq

I want to get a list of all students who were at one of two events.  Here's my function to get an attendance list:

```
Private Function AttendanceList(ByVal Mode As AttendanceListLookupMode, ByVal AttendaceTypeID As Integer, ByVal EventID As Integer, ByVal EventOccurenceDate As Date) As IEnumerable(Of Integer)
        'Get the attendance table for specified event
        Dim resultSet = From a In db.tblAttendances
                        Where a.tblEventOccurence.EventID = EventID _
                            And a.tblEventOccurence.EventOccurenceDate = EventOccurenceDate

        'Apply mode filtering
        Select Case Mode
            Case AttendanceListLookupMode.AttendanceTypeIs
                resultSet = resultSet.Where(Function(x) x.tblAttendanceType.AttendanceTypeID = AttendaceTypeID)
            Case AttendanceListLookupMode.AttendanceTypeIsNot
                resultSet = resultSet.Where(Function(x) x.tblAttendanceType.AttendanceTypeID <> AttendaceTypeID)
        End Select

        'Return the student records
        Return resultSet.Select(Function(x) x.StudentID)
    End Function

    Private Enum AttendanceListLookupMode
        AttendanceTypeIs
        AttendanceTypeIsNot
    End Enum
```

Now I want to use that in a query to check if either event was attended like this:

```
'All students
                Dim resultSet = From s In db.tblStudents

                resultSet = resultSet.Where(Function(x)
                                                AttendanceList(AttendanceListLookupMode.AttendanceTypeIsNot,
                                                               CommonAttendanceTypeIDs.Absent,
                                                               CommonEventIDs.Learning,
                                                               ForDate).Contains(x.StudentID)
                                                Or 
                                                AttendanceList(AttendanceListLookupMode.AttendanceTypeIsNot,
                                                               CommonAttendanceTypeIDs.Absent,
                                                               CommonEventIDs.Basketball,
                                                               ForDate).Contains(x.StudentID)
                                            End Function)
```

When I try to compile this, I get this error:

```
Error   1   Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Where' can be called with these arguments:
Extension method 'Public Function Where(predicate As System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of System.Func(Of tblStudent, Integer, Boolean))) As System.Linq.IQueryable(Of tblStudent)' defined in 'System.Linq.Queryable': Nested function does not have a signature that is compatible with delegate 'System.Func(Of tblStudent, Integer, Boolean)'.
Extension method 'Public Function Where(predicate As System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of System.Func(Of tblStudent, Boolean))) As System.Linq.IQueryable(Of tblStudent)' defined in 'System.Linq.Queryable'.
Extension method 'Public Function Where(predicate As System.Func(Of tblStudent, Integer, Boolean)) As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of tblStudent)' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable': Nested function does not have a signature that is compatible with delegate 'System.Func(Of tblStudent, Integer, Boolean)'.
Extension method 'Public Function Where(predicate As System.Func(Of tblStudent, Boolean)) As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of tblStudent)' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a compiler handy to check, but it looks like you are using the multi-line lambda syntax but specifying a bare expression. The compiler won't like that, it's expecting a statement, not an expression. The two syntaxes differ as follows:

```
Dim singleLinelambda = Function(x) x + 1

Dim multiLineLambda = Function(x)
                          Return x + 1
                      End Function
```

Try this instead:

```
resultSet = resultSet.Where(Function(x)
    Return AttendanceList(AttendanceListLookupMode.AttendanceTypeIsNot,
        CommonAttendanceTypeIDs.Absent,
        CommonEventIDs.Learning,
        ForDate).Contains(x.StudentID) Or
        AttendanceList(AttendanceListLookupMode.AttendanceTypeIsNot,
        CommonAttendanceTypeIDs.Absent,
        CommonEventIDs.Basketball,
        ForDate).Contains(x.StudentID)
    End Function)
```

Personally, I would move the lambda body into a separate method with parameters. It would make the code more readable, e.g.

```
Private Function MyPredicate(Mode As AttendanceListLookupMode, AttendaceTypeID As Integer, EventID1 As Integer, EventID2 As Integer, EventOccurenceDate As Date, StudentID As Integer) As Boolean
    Return AttendanceList(Mode,
        AttendaceTypeID,
        EventID1,
        EventOccurenceDate).Contains(StudentID) Or
        AttendanceList(Mode,
        AttendaceTypeID,
        EventID2,
        EventOccurenceDate).Contains(StudentID)
End Function

' Usage...
resultSet = resultSet.Where(Function(x) MyPredicate(
    AttendanceListLookupMode.AttendanceTypeIsNot,
    CommonAttendanceTypeIDs.Absent,
    CommonEventIDs.Learning,
    CommonEventIDs.Basketball,
    ForDate,
    x.StudentID))
```

Comment: It won't take a statement lambda at all, I did not realize that.  I was able to use the VB line continuation character _ to make my statement lambda an expression lambda and now it compiles.

Comment: Aaaah right, you're using VS2008, sorry. In that case, the multi-line lambda syntax is not available, so doing what you did is better. :-)